# Potential Merge of WebForms to asp.net-webforms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

I'm not really sure being an ASP.NET developer, but do non ASP.NET developers (or ASP.NET developers working on other things) use the tag [webforms](/questions/tagged/webforms) when not talking about ASP.NET web forms? e.g. do PHP developers call their web application pages (or pages with forms) WebForms?

I only ask as when posting a question relating to them I was given the option of [webforms](/questions/tagged/webforms) or [asp.net-webforms](/questions/tagged/asp.net-webforms)

It would seem sensible to make those questions all tagged [asp.net-webforms](/questions/tagged/asp.net-webforms)...but if the tag is ambiguous, that is a big manual effort as there were >900 tagged [webforms](/questions/tagged/webforms)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending a bit of time looking into this, I believe it is pointless to try to make [webforms](/questions/tagged/webforms) ASP.NET-pure.

The [vast majority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webforms+-razor+-.net+-c#+-vb.net+-asp.net*) of the ASP.NET-specific questions in webforms already have a qualifying tag of some sort (the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webforms+-razor+-.net+-c#+-vb.net+-asp.net*) is to questions that aren't clearly ASP.NET). So they're not a problem.

The [vast majority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-webforms+-c#+-.net+-vb.net+-asp.net+-asp.net-mvc+-asp.net-mvc-3+-asp.net-mvc-2+-asp.net-ajax+-asp.net-membership+-asp.net-4.0) of the ASP.NET-specific questions in asp.net-webforms *also* already have some manner of qualifying tag.

So merging and synonymizing [asp.net-webforms](/questions/tagged/asp.net-webforms) into [webforms] would simplify the situation greatly without introducing very much ambiguity (just over 100 questions would benefit from being retagged manually first, **adding** [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net)).

It would also keep the naming consistent: [razor](/questions/tagged/razor) and [webforms](/questions/tagged/webforms) for ASP.NET view engines.

Note that we should *not* be looking for consistency with [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) and [asp.net-ajax](/questions/tagged/asp.net-ajax), as those are actually complete product names (and [as BoltClock mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57628/potential-merge-of-webforms-to-asp-net-webforms/132292#132292), have issues of their own).

Those looking to distinguish ASP.NET's webforms from, say, Drupal's can simply [combine tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webforms+drupal) to produce the desired results.

Comment: Just finished re-tagging a question and had this very same question. Seems worth re-visiting now that we have better tag merging tools available to us and there are around 4k questions in either tag...

Comment: Thanks for the ping, @AnonJr - didn't realize these had been synonymized for over a year but never merged! That's done now.

Comment: Not a problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

[webforms](/questions/tagged/webforms) and [asp.net-webforms](/questions/tagged/asp.net-webforms) should be merged.

[asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) on the other hand should be kept separate, since there are other frameworks building on ASP.NET, that are not WebForms.

Answer (score 2):

I'll agree that most people, when hearing ASP.NET, think of webforms.

Suggest that the tag [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) is a broader set of technologies beneath webforms. There are many technologies or project types extending ASP.NET:

- MVC
- ​WCF
- webforms
- dynamic data
- SOAP web services

ASP.NET is a web application framework. All questions the project types on top deserve their own tag as well.

Comment: WCF does not extend ASP.NET. "SOAP Web Services" extend a very tiny part of ASP.NET, but are now considered to be "legacy technology" by Microsoft, so I wouldn't spend much effort thinking about them. In fact, ASP.NET is a superset, containing web forms, MVC and dynamic data (not WCF).

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not really sure being an ASP.NET developer, but do non ASP.NET developers (or ASP.NET developers working on other things) use the tag [webforms](/questions/tagged/webforms) when not talking about ASP.NET web forms? e.g. do PHP developers call their web application pages (or pages with forms) WebForms?

We don't have a special name for PHP-powered pages/scripts. We just say that we write them in PHP. Neither is PHP itself a framework; it is a language. There do exist major PHP frameworks, but none called WebForms as far as I know.

> It would seem sensible to make those questions all tagged [asp.net-webforms](/questions/tagged/asp.net-webforms)...but if the tag is ambiguous, that is a big manual effort as there were >900 tagged [webforms](/questions/tagged/webforms)...

This is what really bothers me. By now, there's currently quite a divide in the [webforms](/questions/tagged/webforms) tag between questions about ASP.NET WebForms and questions about generic "Web forms" used to refer to, well, forms on the Web, regardless of server technology (or even pure frontend [html](/questions/tagged/html)[css](/questions/tagged/css)[webforms](/questions/tagged/webforms)). The winner, by some margin, is [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net)[webforms](/questions/tagged/webforms), covering almost 1800 questions, with the other 1200-ish being unrelated to ASP.NET.

I'm inclined to go with [what CodeInChaos has proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122177/137537), as [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) itself is the framework used for developing Web apps on the Microsoft stack, and based on that are different sub-frameworks such as ASP.NET WebForms, ASP.NET MVC, etc.

Of course, [ASP.NET MVC has its own taxonomy quandary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126852/vast-majority-of-questions-tagged-asp-net-and-mvc-should-be-tagged-asp-net), but that one is rather unfortunate as "MVC" is a well-known pattern that is almost entirely language and platform agnostic. "Web forms", I feel however, is a different beast...

Comment: Disclaimer: I honestly, truly [have no idea what I'm talking about](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A106224+%5Basp.net%5D).

Comment: reputation and experience count for nothing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Bump. I do support the idea of merge.

[webforms](/questions/tagged/webforms) clearly states that it's related to ASP.NET:

> Web Forms is a part of the ASP.NET web application framework. It is one of the different programming models you can use to create ASP.NET web applications.

Tagging by it anything not related to [asp.net-webforms](/questions/tagged/asp.net-webforms) is tag **misuse** and is **not excuse** do not merge.