# Vast majority of questions tagged [asp.net] and [mvc] should be tagged [asp.net-mvc]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I see that [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc) (13254 so far) is used incorrectly very often.

For example, vast majority of the questions tagged by [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) (or [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)) and [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc) actually should be tagged by [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc), etc.

Only minimal amount of all the questions tagged by this tag are MVC framework independent and are about MVC in general.

Comment: So what you want to do?

Comment: @om-nom-nom: For example retag all [asp.net]+[mvc] with [asp.net-mvc].

Comment: I blame Microsoft for calling it ASP.NET **MVC** in the first place.

Comment: @BoltClock, you can blame Microsoft for almost everything :-).

Comment: Question out of curiosity: Would "general mvc" questions (about the pattern and not a specific framework) be generally more appropriate on Programmers.SE?

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Only if you are [standing in front of a whiteboard.](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/173/1204)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Excellent! Right; that pretty much describes what I was thinking of. It almost seems like a question that's about MVC - but specifically *not* about any particular framework/language - would be a 'whiteboard' type of question. Generally. :p

Comment: What is your questions or suggestion here, in order to be answerable with binary logic

Comment: @LazyBadger: What tagged by both mvc and asp.net-mvc tag only by the second. What tagged by .net or c# and mvc tag by asp.net-mvc instead of mvc.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this will probably require developer intervention and some custom queries.  Community mods and high-rep users have some neat tools to create synonyms and merge tags, but there's little support for chained queries like 'convert all questions tagged both [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) and [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc)

[Here is a link to a search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc+asp.net) for questions tagged [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) and [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc), there are currently 3,283 questions with both tags out of 14,443 total uses of the [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc) tag.   That's a 22.7% takeover. Sure, it's possible that some of these questions ought to be tagged in this way.  However, any questions about implementing an MVC architecture on the ASP.NET platform without using ASP.NET-MVC are going to state that distinction clearly in the question, and the vast majority (from a cursory inspection, every one of the first 50 questions) are mis-tagged.

Even worse, 557 are tagged [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net), [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc), and [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc). [Here's a link to the search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc+asp.net+asp.net-mvc).  That sort of abuse (specifically, posting a question with tags that are purely combinations of other tags) should be auto-detected and prevented.