# Misunderstood MVC tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I've seen a lot – really a LOT –  of questions on Stack Overflow that have the [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc) tag, but are not related at all to the architectural pattern. Instead, they seem to refer to some .NET technology (I'm a Java guy, so maybe I'm wrong here). Some examples:

- [Could not find file PrecompiledApp.config when working with precompiled Razor views and VirtualPathProviders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428030/could-not-find-file-precompiledapp-config-when-working-with-precompiled-razor-vi)
- [MVC 3.0 ModelBinder bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key) returns null when binding in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179601/mvc-3-0-modelbinder-bindingcontext-valueprovider-getvaluekey-returns-null-when)
- [.NET MVC Custom viewengine layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705728/net-mvc-custom-viewengine-layout)

What's the proper thing to do when I find these questions? Retag, or just ignore because it is a general practice?

Comment: Related: [Vast majority of questions tagged \[asp.net\] and \[mvc\] should be tagged \[asp.net-mvc\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126852/vast-majority-of-questions-tagged-asp-net-and-mvc-should-be-tagged-asp-net) (except in this case none of the questions have the [asp.net] tag)

Comment: I always confuse it with motor vehicle collision, and these questions have nothing to do with motor vehicle collisions. I support your retag request. *(there are also [jsp] and [mvc] questions, so this isn't a problem restricted to .Net)*

Comment: You may want to participate in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012 as to the tag cleanup.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, ASP.NET MVC *does* use the MVC architectural pattern.

If it really bothers you, just retag them [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc)

Comment: "just"? :) There are pretty a lot.

Comment: I guess the real question is: Which of those questions should just be retagged, and which are genuinely asking about the MVC pattern (whether or not they're asking in the context of ASP.net). You'd have to actually read them all to know the answer to that, and as @Chichiray says, there are a lot of them.

Comment: Any questions that have the tags [asp.net] and [mvc] are almost certainly about the [mvc] pattern, as specifically implemented in [asp.net-mvc]. Alas, there are no automated retagging tools that would make this any easier, but [it's simple enough to find these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net+mvc).