# Rename mvc tag into mvc-pattern

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I know this has been discussed before about the [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc) tag. See: [Misunderstood MVC tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132738/misunderstood-mvc-tag)

Could we work to rename this tag to something like [mvc-pattern](/questions/tagged/mvc-pattern) and <strike>blacklist</strike> make a synonym the old one?

Comment: There is no blacklist.  The blacklist is only available to SE developers, and there is a cost, so it is only used in very extreme cases.  I don't see what adding "pattern" to the tag would fix.

Comment: "mvc" is always used in the sense of "mvc-pattern", what will this solve?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel a lot of people mistakenly ignore the documentation for it and tag it when they mean [tag:asp.net-mvc]

Comment: @DanielA.White: I'm aware of that, but I strongly doubt that they will now refrain from using it. In their eyes, the mvc-pattern is applicable because it is about "<X> MVC"

Comment: @DanielA.White does `asp.net-mvc` not use the MVC pattern?

Comment: @SamIam it does, but most of the questions relate to the framework, not the pattern.

Comment: @DanielA.White `"it does"` and `"most of the questions relate to ... not the pattern"` sound mutually exclusive to me.  Unless the OP is actually not using, or intending to use the MVC pattern, than the `mvc` tag seems correct to me

Comment: @SamIam its not correct in my eyes since they could be asking a question about razor, which is a view rendering engine, but it has nothing to do with the mvc pattern.

Comment: @DanielA.White but they're still using the `MVC` pattern, It still gives you potentially useful context for the question.

Comment: @SamIam, no, no it doesn't.  A large number (even a majority) of the questions use(d) [tag:mvc] aren't actually *about* the pattern, but simply including the tag because they're using a framework that claims to implement the pattern.  The tag is mostly used as **noise**.  The rename done below should help reduce the noise ... well, at least when people pay attention to their tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reversed the synonym [model-view-controller](/questions/tagged/model-view-controller) --> [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc) and merged, so that they will all read [model-view-controller](/questions/tagged/model-view-controller).  I doubt anyone will mistake that for [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc).

Comment: i'd be fine with that.

Comment: Sadly, it has made no impact on amount of ASP.NET MVC posts that are mis-tagged as [tag:model-view-controller]. We are not dealing with a typo. Those people **actually** think the ASP.NET MVC and MVC pattern are one and the the same thing.