# Aliasing of webforms tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

What was the reasoning behind merge of [asp.net-webforms](/questions/tagged/asp.net-webforms) -> [webforms](/questions/tagged/webforms)?

That seems like an extremely harmful thing to do. Especially in the context that there is a [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-web-forms-2-20060821/) and Drupal-thing with the same name. It's kinda akin to aliasing [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) -> [sql](/questions/tagged/sql).

What prompted this choice? Was it done only because ASP.NET community was not able to inspect and re-tag (if necessary) 5000 posts?

Comment: This seems to explain it: [Potential Merge of WebForms to asp.net-webforms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57628/potential-merge-of-webforms-to-asp-net-webforms)?

Comment: You might notice that response from mods was not unanimous. I already read that post, when looking for the reasoning this step.

Comment: Which is why I did not vote to close this as a dupe. Though I guess it explains the situation. But let's see if this gathers some more insights.